# How to infer the shape of the output when connecting convolution layer with dense layers?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to construct a Convolutional Neural Network using `pytorch` and can not understand how to interpret the input neurons for the first densely connected layer. Say, for example, I have the following architecture:

```
self.conv_layer = nn.Sequential(
   nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5),
   nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5),
   nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
   nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5),
   nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 5),
   nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2))

self.fc_layer = nn.Sequential(
   nn.Linear(X, 512),
   nn.Linear(512, 128),
   nn.Linear(128, 10))
```

Here `X` would be the number of neurons in the first linear layer. So, do I need to keep track of the shape of the output tensor at each layer so that I can figure out `X`?

Now, I can put the values in the formula `(W - F + 2P) / S + 1` and calculate the shape after each layer, that would be somewhat convenient.

Isn't there something even more convenient which might do this automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use `LazyLinear` layer: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html.

According to the documentation:

> A `torch.nn.Linear` module where `in_features` is inferred ... They will be initialized after the first call to `forward` is done and the module will become a regular `torch.nn.Linear` module. The `in_features` argument of the Linear is inferred from the `input.shape[-1]`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really convenient solution and requires no extra effort and is really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go through the layers and compute the output shapes iteratively, you can do an inference on the CNN part of your model by defining it offline:

```
cnn = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5),
    nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),

    nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5),
    nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 5),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2))
```

For instance, if you have an input shaped `(1, 3, 100, 100)`:

```
>>> cnn(torch.empty(1, 3, 100, 100)).shape
torch.Size([1, 128, 19, 19])
```

So the number of features in the first fully connected dense layer should be:

```
>>> cnn(torch.empty(1, 3, 100, 100)).numel()
46208
```